# Why is there resistance present between Power supply terminals even in off condition?

Tags: power-supply, power, resistance

I would like to know why there is a resistance between power supply terminals even when power supply is turned off?

Comment: Do you mean : Why are you able to get a value of resistance using a multimeter on a switched off device ? Because the answer will be different.

Comment: Yes , you are right i mean the same.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what the circuit does when you turn off the supply.  This will vary between supplies, but apparently you have one that presents a low resistance when off.  Power supplies are not usually specified as to what they look like electrically when off, so most likely there is nothing wrong.  Some supplies might appear high impedance when off, others low, others high up to a junction drop or two and then much lower.

The off characteristics of the supply is not something people generally care about, so they aren't usually deliberately designed for.  As a result, they fall out from other circuit design decisions, and can vary widely from supply to supply.

Comment: The OP might be referring to the power supply terminals *on the load*.

Comment: @Dave: Hmm, I suppose you could interpret the question that way. We shouldn't have to guess, so -1 for a badly written question.

Comment: A coworker once had a fluorescent lamp which exhibited an interesting behavior: if it was unplugged while switched on, the leads would have a potential across them that was somewhat higher than the peak mains voltage.  Touching the leads of the unplugged lamp would give a nasty jolt; shorting them would cause the lamp to flash briefly.  The coworker discarded the lamp before I could find out what exactly was going on, but I thought that behavior was odd (esp. the higher-than-peak-mains voltage).  I think regulatory agencies want devices to discharge caps within some timeframe.